# Elasticsearch uses more memory than JVM heap settings allow

Tags: elasticsearch, memory, memory-leaks, centos

The link [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/advanced-configuration.html#set-jvm-heap-size) from the official elasticsearch documentation, mentioning that to limit elasticsearch memory use, you have to set the value of `Xms` and `Xmx` to the proper value.

Current setup is:

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
```

On my server, I am using CentOS8, elastic search is using more memory than it is allowed in the JVM heap settings and causing the server to crash.

The following errors observed at the same time:

```
[2021-09-06T13:11:08,810][WARN ][o.e.m.f.FsHealthService  ] [dev.localdomain] health check of [/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] took [8274ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5s]
[2021-09-06T13:11:20,579][WARN ][o.e.c.InternalClusterInfoService] [dev.localdomain] Failed to update shard information for ClusterInfoUpdateJob within 15s timeout
[2021-09-06T13:12:14,585][WARN ][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] [dev.localdomain] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
```

at the same times the following errors issued on `/var/log/messages`

```
Sep 6 13:11:08 dev kernel: out_of_memory+0x1ba/0x490
Sep 6 13:11:08 dev kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 277068 (elasticsearch) total-vm:4145008kB, anon-rss:3300504kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:86876kB, UID:1001
```

Am I missing some settings to limit elasticsearch memory usage?

Comment: they are warnings, not errors, and not related to memory. how are you determining that it's using more than what you have defined in your heap?

Comment: I can see out of memory errors at the same time those errors issued. on /var/log/messages

Comment: I will update them on the question.

Comment: what else is on the host, how much memory does it have?

Comment: I have MySQL DB and it has 12GBs of memory

Comment: 1GB of heap for Elasticsearch is pretty low, does it help if you increase it. also we don't recommend running multiple processes like this on an Elasticsearch host, due to this reason

Comment: @MarkWalkom regardless the amount assigned, why the service is using more than it should?

Comment: have you locked Elasticsearch's memory?

Comment: No it is not locked, will try that